# Having problems compiling my first C++ program

Tags: c++, xcode

I tried compiling the following program on XCode on my Mac, and I get these errors:

*Non-ASCII charactes are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers. Fix it: Delete ""
*Use of undeclared identifier 'Hello'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << “Hello there world!”;
    return 0;
}
```

This program is literally verbatim from the textbook, "A First Book of C++: An Introduction to Programming" so I'm not sure why it would not work. Is this a Mac vs. PC issue?

Comment: Are you using a plain text editor or a word processor?

Comment: Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: The error should actually have an arrow pointing to that quotation mark ([Clang does for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29176b4463e93ad)). Referencing any ASCII table, you'll see that the only quotation mark character is ", which is the only one that should be on the keyboard.

Comment: I'm using Xcode. But I think the problem was that I directly copied and pasted from a textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "pretty quotes" copied from your textbook are not valid characters.

Change:

```
cout << “Hello there world!”;
//      ^                  ^ These characters are not correct.
```

To:

```
cout << "Hello there world!";
```

The editor you use to type code **must not** be one that replaces the characters you type with characters that might *look nicer*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using non-ASCII double quotes

Answer (score 0):

try with this string (cut and paste) "Hello there world", note the different leading apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Code::Blocks compiler

http://www.codeblocks.org/